# Enlazar carpeta compartida en Ubuntu con VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Tengo instalado Ubuntu, a través de VirtualBox.
he creado una ruta de carpeta en VirtualBox para tener una carpeta compartida, y he creado también una carpeta a través del terminal en Ubuntu.

El problema viene cuando intento enlazarlas con la orden:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf Dades_Compartides /mnt/compartit
```

y me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

> mount: can't find comp/mnt/compartit in /etc/fstab

¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/mnt/compartit` debe ser un directorio existente.

Comment: Gracias, al final re instale todo y me funciono